PyTorch training killed after few epochs
PyTorch training was killed after a few epochs.
(The model which is trained is Faster RCNN, I'm not sure, that it is important)
It happened both on the local PC and on EC2 AWS.
When it happens, Chrome crashes.
The only message I've got was:
2622547 killed      python src/train.py

The screenshot is attached.

